# c# Sum of the values from list

Tags: c#, algorithm

```
   int [] myList = {7, 11, 17, 5, 18, 6};

   int sum=0;

   a1 = value1(7);
   a2 = value1(7) + value2(11);
   a3 = value1(7) + value2(11) + value3(17);
   ....
   ....
   ....
   a6 = value1(7) + value2(11) + value3(17) + ... + value6(6);

   return sum = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6;
```

**Example:**

I have a an array --> `[7, 11, 17, 5, 18, 6]`

and I have to assign a value to `sum`.

`sum` must be =

```
  7 +
  7 + 11 +
  7 + 11 + 17 +
  7 + 11 + 17 + 5 +
  7 + 11 + 17 + 5 + 18 +
  7 + 11 + 17 + 5 + 18 + 6 =

  (7*6 + 11*5 + 17*4 + 5*3 + 18*2 + 6) = 222
```

(Note, I don't want a *simple sum* of the array's items.)
how can I code this on c#?

Comment: You want a total sum of the array?

Comment: @VimalPatel no, the final sum must be = (7x6 + 11x5 + 17x4 + 5x3 + 18x2 + 6). I dont want the sum of array

Comment: For loop with index, start fromthe end, multiply each value with the index

Comment: `int result = myList.Select((v, i) => v * (myList.Length - i)).Sum();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have the formula:

```
 sum = item[0] * Length + 
       item[1] * (Length - 1) + 
       ...
       item[i] * (Length - i) +
       ...
       item[Length - 1] * 1
```

In order to implement it, you can use good old `for` loop:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < myList.Length; ++i)
  sum += myList[i] * (myList.Length - i);
```

or Linq:

```
int sum = myList
  .Select((item, i) => item * (myList.Length - i))
  .Sum();
```

**Edit:** If you want to *generalize* the solution for `IEnuerable<int>` where we *don't know* `Length` or `Count` you can put `foreach` loop:

```
int sum = 0;
int prior = 0;

// Now myList can be int[] (array), List<int> (list)...
foreach (int item in myList) 
  sum += (prior += item);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `linq`

```
var totalLength = myList.Length;
var totalSum = myList.Select((m, index) => m * (totalLength  - index)).Sum();
```

Another way:

```
int sum = 0;
var cummulativeSum = myList.Select(m => { sum = sum + m; return sum;});
totalSum = cummulativeSum.Sum();
```

Check the fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q6s4OT

Comment: In your solution above you have left out the final '.Sum()'. It is present in your fiddle tough.

Comment: @MrCodingB - Fixed the fiddle. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```cs
using System.Linq;

int[] myList = {7, 11, 17, 5, 18, 6};
        
var sum = myList.Select((e, i) => e * (myList.Length - i)).Sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int [] myList = {7,11,17,5,18,6};

var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < myList.Length; i++)
{
    sum += myList[i] * (myList.Length - i);
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        int[] myList = { 7, 11, 17, 5, 18, 6 };
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i=1; i<= myList.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{(myList.Length - i + 1)}*{myList[i-1]}");
            sum += (myList.Length-i+1) * myList[i-1];
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"sum: {sum}");
```

or

```
        using System.Linq;

        int[] myList = { 7, 11, 17, 5, 18, 6 };

        int j = myList.Length;
        var sum = myList.Aggregate(0, (total, x) => total+=x*j--);
        Console.WriteLine($"sum: {sum}");
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

var myList = new int[] { 7, 11, 17, 5, 18, 6 };

var sum = myList.Reverse()
    .Select((v, i) => v * (i + 1))
    .Sum();

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

P.S. Updated [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TksLSh).

Comment: I've seen the update, I'll correct in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to solving this here is one:

```
int [] myList = {7, 11, 17, 5, 18, 6};
var result = myList.SelectMany((x, i) => myList.GetRange(0, i + 1)).Sum();
```

If I break this down into small pieces

```
int [] myList = {7, 11, 17, 5, 18, 6};

var grouped = myList.Select((x, i) => myList.GetRange(0, i + 1));
// grouped = {{7},{7,11},{7,11,17},{7,11,17,5},{7,11,17,5,18},{7,11,17,5,18,6}}

var flattened = grouped.SelectMany(x => x);
// flattened = {7,7,11,7,11,17,7,11,17,5,7,11,17,5,18,7,11,17,5,18,6}

var sum = flattened.Sum();
// sum = 222
```